# 43 special points on the nine point circle

Tags: geometry

One often reads that there are (at least) 43 special points on the nine point circle of triangle geometry. Can anybody give me a reference which contains an explicit description
of them (preferably accessible i.e. on internet or in a good---but not great---university library)?

with thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a special point? Are you looking for points which divide segment in a ratio, or point of concurrence,intersection of some lines or something else.

Comment: see the Weisstein page about the [Nine-Point Circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nine-PointCircle.html) and the link after (3) to the indices of the [Kimberling centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) as proposed by Joseph.

Comment: @Raymond: thanks, just what i was looking for, jbc

Comment: @jbc: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You might look at some of what is on Clark Kimmerling's web page:  http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/